# XPath and wildcard in AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, xpath, wildcard

Any idea why is objProperties, an xpath with wildcard, in ...
...

```
function getXMLServerObject (httpType, cmd, isAsync) {
    var object = new Array();
    $.ajax({
      type: httpType,
      url: cmd,
      async: isAsync,
      dataType: "xml",
      success: function (xml) {
        var error = $(xml).find("Error");
        if (error == null) {
            object["__error"] = error.text();
            return object;
        }
        var objProperties = $(xml).find("Data\\Record\\*");
```

... of zero length for xml:

...

```
<Data>
    <Record>
        <MailFrequency>30</MailFrequency>
        <Tracking>-1</Tracking>
    </Record>
</Data>
```

Find on individual nodes returns proper results

Comment: Did the answers help you? If not, did you solve it yourself? If yes, please accept one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery isn't designed to use XPath as it's selectors.

Once you wrap xml in jQuery object, think of the tags the same way you would html tags and use exact same jQuery selector and methods approach

Assuming you have multiple `<Record>` try:

```
var $records = $(xml).find("Record");/* create collection of all Record tags */

$records.each(function(){
  var $children=$(this).children();
   /* or to access specific elements*/
   var mailFreq= $(this).find('MailFrequency').text();
})
```

Comment: success: function(xml) {
                ...
        
                var $records = $(xml).find("Record"); 
                if (($records).size() > 1) ...
    
                $records.each(function(){
                    var $children=$(this).children();
                    $children.each(function(){
                        var key = $(this).prop("tagName");
                        var value = $(this).text();
                        object[key] = value;
                    });
                });
        },

Comment: Yes! Don't know how to format comment although I appear to be following the rules (this is my fist stackoverflow posting).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the line

```
var objProperties = $(xml).find("Data\\Record\\*");
```

I would assume that you mean `"Data\\Record\\*"` to be your XPath expression. I don't know of any XPath engine that accepts `\` as a separator. You would usually use `/`: `"Data/Record/*"`.

Aside from that, you can actually achieve the same thing with jQuery selectors which is a super-set of CSS3 selectors. Keep in mind that the root node is `Data` and `$.find` only works on children:

```
var objProperties = $(xml).find("Record > *");
```

This won't be a proper object of the elements inside each record. If you want that you need to use [charlietfl's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24713014/1816580) with a little adjustment.

Comment: I tried both. None does the work but I get errors with /

Then I saw jqWidgets using \

Will learn jQuery better, these are my early days.

Comment: It is a descendant, I just didn't copy entire file, apologies.